# How do I append values from one column to another range, based on matching values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to compare lists like the ones below for duplicate values. Then extract the duplicates from column Q, and append the names in that align with the duplicates to column T.

[image: https://imgur.com/7YXdYKn]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use Index/match

```
=INDEX(P:P,MATCH(T5,Q:Q,0))
```

I am totally guessing on the row in the `T5`.  Change that to the correct first row and copy the formula down.

Comment: Would I be able to use this same formula if the matches could exist in an array that is more than a single column wide?

Comment: that is a different question.  This answers this question, please ask a new question with example data.